# JQuery Replace a Textbox with a DropDownList

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

After selecting an item in a different DropDownList, I want to change a textbox on the page with a DropdownList (the change happens is a bool is true that besides).

```
$('#InvoiceNumber').replaceWith($(@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text"), "Choose a category")));
```

But the following error occurs:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Why is this occuring?

Comment: It causes the error becasue replacewith works with a string and I'm trying to insert HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `replaceWith()` you are using the `Html.DropDownList()` helper method to generate HTML that you have wrapped with a jQuery selector `$()`.

The jQuery selector looks to be superfluous:

```
$('#InvoiceNumber').replaceWith(@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text"), "Choose a category"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#InvoiceNumber').replaceWith($('@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text"), "Choose a category")'));
```

This should work too:

```
 $('#InvoiceNumber').replaceWith('@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text"), "Choose a category")');
```