# JQuery .ReplaceWith a Html.DropDownList Helper

Tags: jquery, replace, html-helper

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830959/jquery-replace-a-textbox-with-a-dropdownlist) post which lokos to be exactly what I am looking for (although I am on MVC 5) but none of the replies here seem to help me.

I have the following:

```
$('#ContactEventTypeHeader1', li).replaceWith($('@Html.DropDownList("ddContactEventName", ViewBag.ContactEventNames as SelectList, new { @id = "ddContactEventNameId" })'));
```

but it just simply refuses to work. Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `$('#ContactEventTypeHeader1', li)` is not undefined ?

Comment: Wha'ts the error ? (js console error, rendering razor error, rendered result page error, no action ...)